# Oil substitution for butter in pastry recipe

Tags: oil, butter, pastry

I have just made a pastie in a pie dish using S.Burt's recipe [Can I substitute olive oil for butter/shortening in pie crust?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22709/can-i-substitute-olive-oil-for-butter-shortening-in-pie-crust). It was really delicious but has no strength. I used rice oil and lite milk and did not rest the pastry. I used plain all purpose 9.7% protein flour. Can anyone advise how to get a stronger pastry so that the pastie is contained by the pastry and doesn't need a pie dish?

Comment: ... rice oil?  I'm not familiar with that ingredient, could it have properties that might be a factor?

Comment: I'm not sure, it is bland and has a high smoke point.And I'm trying to avoid animal fats from a healthy heart perspective.

Comment: @Megha there isn't anything special about rice oil, it is highly refined and behaves virtually identical to other stuff labeled "vegetable oil".

Comment: I like to add bacon fat to my pancakes instead of butter, my kids still don’t know why dads pancakes are so delicious lol

Comment: Also, don't forget that butter is only 75% fat and 25% water/milk solids. So if you change to a pure fat, reduce it to 75% and add some water or milk to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional Cornish Pasty pastry is made with 1 part strong bread flour, 1/4 part each of butter and lard, about 1/3 part water, and about 1% of the flour's weight in salt. The pastry is worked quite hard, almost like a bread dough, and left to rest for a good hour. The resulting pastry is leathery enough to withstand a miner's pocket, faintly crisp on the outside, (with an egg-wash), and slightly gooey where it meets the filling ingredients, which are introduced raw, and cooked in the pastry.

Doing the sums, that's about 450g of fat to a kilo of flour,and 380g of water. Bread flour is 12-15% protein, higher than yours. The stronger your flour mixture, the more pliable the result.. the more oil, the more prone to crumbling (pure oil> shortbread.. pure water>something like a salt crust which it might take a hammer to break)

If I was experimenting with oils, I would combine the oil with the flour first, (probably in a food processor - it doesn't matter if it's overworked) and introduce the water slowly, until a coherent ball is formed, bearing in mind the paste will become more pliable after resting.

For a Cornish Pasty, the paste is rolled quite thick, about 5mm, cut with a dinner-plate as a guide, back half flopped over the pin to be filled, then folded over, and crimped.

Forgive me if I've misunderstood what you mean by 'Pasty' .. but then, I come from that part of the world.. :)  But it might, anyway, be an informative parallel to the kind of pasty you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Mix only the milk with some of the flour and knead like making a bread dough. Next, roll the dough ito a flat sheet.

Mix the rest of the flour with the oil and spread the mixture on the sheet. Roll up the sheet like a jelly roll and then into a coil. Roll flat the coil and use it as your pastry for foldovers or empanadas.

This link will demonstrate in detail: [Huaiyang  Chinese  Pastry](http://www.recipies.50webs.com/Huaiyang%20chinese%20pastry%20.htm)